# What does the notation f(t)1(t) signify?

Tags: functions, notation, transformation, control-theory

I've come across this notation in a text on Control Theory, Modern Control Engineering by Katsuhiko Ogata, in a discussion of Laplace transforms. There is little more context I can give than that.

The exact example involves the translation of function $f(t)1(t)$ to $f(t-a)1(t-a)$, so my guess was that it signified some sort of transformation, but I really have no clue.

Google turned up nothing helpful, as did a search on this forum. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1(t-t_0)$ is simply the step function, also denoted $u(t-t_0)$. $1(t)$ means $u(t-t_0)$ with  $t_0=0$.

[image: Step function]

Its value is $0$ before $t_0$, and $1$ after $t_0$. [More info on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function).

The $1(t)$ is the unit step function and the $f(t)$ is just some other function and when multiplied they can represent some variable signal starting at time $t_0$.

Comment: Ah, so the $1(t)$ is the unit step function and the $f(t)$ is just a regular function, and when multiplied they represent some variable signal which starts at time $t_0$.

Comment: Edited and accepted.

Comment: The last paragraph in the answer as it now stands was added by Ian, except that I have set the mathematical notation there and elsewhere in the posting in MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is just the author's way of denoting a step function. There doesn't seem to be a reason given for using it.

Comment: It says I have to wait a day